# Appengine ImportError: No module named webob after upgrade to Mavericks on Mac

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.5

I deploy using command line. After upgrading to Mavericks OS I tried to deploy and got the message 'can't find the appengine sdk'. I recreated the symlinks and it got past that error and instead now shows me:

ImportError: No module named webob

There are 3 webob folders within the usr/local/google_appengine/lib folder: webob_0_9 and versions -1.1.1, -1.2.3 so it certainly is there to import

I'm using python2.5 with appengine patch. The other entries on this problem are limited and have not helped. I upgraded the sdk to the latest version, as instructed, still the same prpblem. Also, I figured that maybe my problem was something unique to the Mavericks OS upgrade

Just for the hell of it, i renamed one of the folders to webob (rather than webob_0_9) and then it gave me a new error:  ImportError: cannot import name dev_appserver

UPDATE: 
The upgrade to Mavericks OS did wipe out some of the site packages in python including pip and webob. So I reinstalled both pip and webob and I also downgraded my SDK version to 1.6.4 because of further errors (caused by my attempt to fix the problem by upgrading to 1.9.6)

Comment: Appengine Patch is long deprecated.  Recommend updating to django-nonrel and python 2.7.

Comment: i would love to do that but it would be a hell of a pain right now and I have to fix bugs first and get the current version running before i can upgrade

Comment: The docs say the python 2.5 runtime only supports webob 0.9, so that is the version you want to import.  The migration from 2.5 to 2.7 is not too bad.  You should at least do that.  Then you can include the webob library in app.yaml.

Comment: an upgrade to python 2.7 also requires an upgrade to HRD (we are on old master / slave). I've been through this process and we need to make some changes to db models + code for this to work smoothly (due to unique key problems). Right now, that is not an option for me. I'm thinking that if it was working before I upgraded the mac OS, then maybe the problem is related to sys.path / python path settings or something a lot simpler.

Comment: try, from Terminal: `sudo pip install webob==0.9`, or put `usr/local/google_appengine/lib` on your sys.path. To check path, in Terminal, type `echo $PATH`. Read: http://architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/

Comment: that was a very useful article. I've added it and I still have the same problem but I'm not alone with mavericks upgraded and python problems http://attentionshard.wordpress.com/2013/10/25/os-x-mavericks-fixing-broken-python-development-environments/ I will follow the trail and report back here when I have the fix

Comment: Yep, upgrade to mavericks wiped out webob and pip. I reinstalled pip, reinstalled webob. This got me past the webob error. Then I also had to downgrade my appengine sdk to 1.6.4 and then it finally deployed. Sunofab****! Thank you very much for your help GAEfan. I would have been going in circles had it not been for eliminating other options.

Comment: I also had to downgrade my appengine sdk to 1.6.4.  Thank you so much for this tip.